# Javascript inheritance chainng access to the first parent properties

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6

I've been trying to use ES6 and chain a few classes since I want to use the Single responsibility. Maybe my  approach is not very right but that is what I managed to come up with.

I have a few classes.

`class Application{};`

`class Builder extends Application{};`

`class Block extends Builder{};`

Now my question is if I have in the `Application class` a property `this.name` for example.

How can I access that name in the `Block class` from the `Application Class`?

Comment: Simply use 'this.name' in your Block class. Also don't forget to add 'super()' to your constructor.

Comment: While you haven't shown what these classes do, I suspect you're still violating the single responsibility principle. You're not writing a block application. You want to write an application where a builder works with (multiple, even) blocks. They should not be subclasses of each other.

Comment: Yes I made a mistake there for sure. I Extended the Application cuz I needed access to the properties of it. But when I use super() and this.name it doesn't reffer to the name of the Application sadly. Nvm i Found a workaround, thanks, I don't chaing inheritance anymore :P